# Implementing UICollectionView cell for items with variable number of subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

## Problem

- I have a UICollectionView initialised from code and I register a custom class for its cells. The custom class has a few UIStackViews to lay out a bunch of UILabels and UIViews.
- One of the arranged subviews should contain a variable number of  UIViews. To make this less abstract, let’s think of them as “seats" that will display faces of users attending this event (can be up to four, can be none)

## Solutions that come to mind

(I’m a novice)

### Solution 1

- Have the custom class lay out all the "seat" UIViews so I can treat them as placeholders;
- Have the UICollectionView’s cellForItemAt method iterate over the data source and unhide the “seats” that have been filled

### Solution 2

- Make sure that the UIStackView in the custom class can be referenced from UICollectionView’s cellForItemAt method
- From cellForItemAt use addArrangedSubview to add all the needed “seats”

### Solution 3

- Register 5 different classes (zero “seats” to “four seats”)
- Dequeue each one as dictated by the data source
- This one seems to me like the least dignified, but might be the one with least performance penalty

I'm perfectly aware that there could be more, and better, solutions. So, what would be the optimal way of implementing this variable number of UIViews, and why?

EDIT:

While I think that the layout of the cell here is irrelevant, it's been requested that I post it 
[so here it is...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeKHn.png)

Comment: so you mean number of blue circles are not fix and UILabel's count are fix.  blue circles count could change . right ?

Comment: Correct @HiteshAgarwal

Comment: Okay, I am not sure I quite get your question but let me give you my advice.
So this layout you pasted, this is supposed to be one CollectionViewCell? If so and it is vertical, I would use TableView instead. Also the seats you are displaying with those circles, I would replace that with CollectionView which is a perfect solution for dynamic number of cell. See the sketch for idea:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r10frf70ytp9mmp/Screenshot%202018-03-23%2010.17.08.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose Solution 3, as it will be much more performant.
Also, I have two advices:

1. Avoid using `UIStackView`, as it has slow layout performance (it is based on `AutoLayout`). Also, try to avoid `AutoLayout` in `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell` for better performance. Here are some of the most popular and powerful open source layout libraries [PinLayout](https://github.com/mirego/PinLayout), [LayoutKit](https://github.com/linkedin/LayoutKit).
2. You can write base `UICollectionViewCell`, move all of the relevant logic there, and then just make all the needed subclasses with minimal logic overriding.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it made me research your claims and verify that REUSING really is the key here, so I did exactly what you wrote in #2. However, I'm keeping UIStackView for now, hoping it will help me with Dynamic Type optimisation. Thank you!